# jQuery Grab Value of Dynamic Textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea, field, dynamic-text

Suppose you have a textarea (`id="fred"`) that appends (`.append()`) or replaces (`.html()`) another element. The textarea's submit button is called via delegate to send the *modified* text blurb in the textarea... How do you select the modified textblurb, as opposed to what was originally put in the textarea via the first delegate?

Answer (score 1):

mea culpa... `val()` does the trick